# Ubuntu 18.04 - fuse: device not found

Tags: 18.04, sshfs, fuse

I'm trying to make SSHFS work in my Ubuntu 18.04 version (bionic).

I run the following command:

```
sudo sshfs -o idmap=user xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/path/to/remote /path/to/local
```

I get the following error

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

So I did

```
modprobe fuse
```

And got the following:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
                                                          
modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you use Ubuntu as Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) ??? I got the same error using Ubunto in combination with WSL

Comment: Any luck? I got the same error in WSL Ubuntu 20.04